# Ruby on Rails - Combining #or and #joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, merge, union

I'm working on a RoR application and I'm running into the following problem: I have a model `A` that `belongs_to` up to two separate instances of another model `B`, and I want to define a scope that returns all instances of `A` for which some condition holds for either of the instances of `B` using a scope of `B`. Pseudo-code:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :first,  class_name: "B", dependent: :destroy, optional: true
  belongs_to :second, class_name: "B", dependent: :destroy, optional: true

  # How to properly do this?
  scope :A_scope, lambda { left_outer_joins(:first).merge(B.B_scope).or(left_outer_joins(:second).merge(B.B_scope)) }
end
```

where:

```
class B < Application Record
  scope :B_scope, lambda { .. }
end
```

I've tried several variations, but I keep running into the problem that it either: runs but doesn't return what I want it to, or it gives an `ArgumentError`:

```
ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:left_outer_joins])
```

Comment: Note: In Ruby 1.9+ you can write this with the "stabby lambda", as in `-> { ... }` instead of the old `lambda` style.

Comment: I think it's saying you can't do a conditional join. You must do all the joins and *then* apply conditions. Maybe you want a `UNION`?

Comment: I was under the impression that `or` was the way to go for performing unions. I do realize why the error is raised in this case, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to properly do this. :( By union, do you mean to use a raw SQL query with the `UNION` statement? If possible, I'd very much like to reuse `B_scope`..

Comment: This would be way easier in a relational many-to-many table, but if you're stuck with this structure I think a `UNION` would express it better.

Comment: So by `UNION` do you mean that I should use a raw SQL query in this case? I'd prefer reusing existing scopes if possible.

Comment: I think you can keep it in ActiveRecord if you use extensions like [ActiveRecordUnion](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union). Personally I'd suggest using a many-to-many as things like this violate the [Zero, One, or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) as applied to schema design, but it's your call.

Comment: I'm not sure if the extension you linked does the job - it seems to return instances of `B` for my example. I've thought about it some more, and there may actually be a use case for having more than two associated instances in my case so I think I'm going to add a join table `C` that has some extra data that allows me to discern the `first` and `second` instances. How would you define `A_scope` in this setup?

Comment: A join table solves a lot of problems here. It has `belongs_to :A` and `belongs_to :B` and probably a column that represents its `position` like an `INT` for "first" = 1, "second" = 2, etc. Then you can easily fetch all, or just the "firsts" or whatever. Add a unique index on `a_id, b_id, position` and you're pretty much done, or even just `a_id, b_id` if you can have one record in multiple "positions".

Comment: Given this setup, I'd still like to be able to do: return all `A` for which some condition (defined via scope in `B`) holds for _any_ of the associated records in `C`. How would you approach that?

Comment: I think a `has_many :through` from A to B and/or vice-versa could cover that.

Comment: Hang on, my bad, I was overcomplicating things in my head. The query turns out to be a lot easier than I anticipated given this setup. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: If you do end up with a working solution, a self-answer would help.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll add it when I've got it working.